# How to fetch entity model connection string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Given this entity model variable:

```
DataBaseEntities db = new DataBaseEntities ();
```

The below code can not use from db varibale connection string

```
SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(db.Connection.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is

Comment: @BenRobinson the point is that SqlBulkCopy works with standard SQL Connection Strings and not with Entity Connection Strings, see my answer below. question is clear in my opinion. Or at least I've got it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this approach:

```
private string GetADOConnectionString()
{
    var db = new DataBaseEntities();

    EntityConnection ec = (EntityConnection)db.Connection;

    return ec.StoreConnection.ConnectionString;
}
```

I've found this here: [Getting SqlConnection from EntityConnection](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2009/11/getting-sqlconnection-from.html)

also see here: [EntityConnection.StoreConnection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.storeconnection.aspx)

**Edit:** of course this should be adapted and you should check for nulls or check before casting... it's just an example ;-)

Comment: You don't need to cast to `SqlConnection`

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim objEntities As New DBEntities
```

I have the connection string already set within .edmx file in my project.

Comment: I was trying to explain, that if you set it this way, you might not need to take the approach you were in your original post.  Just a suggestion. no need for the vote down 

You were so vague in your question it was very hard to understand what you were wanting to begin with

Comment: I didnt vote you down dude and i got 3 down votes in a row on old questions and answers of mine. are you trying to revenge for something I did not do to you? Also notice that I am NOT the opener of the question.

Comment: No revenge on my part.  Sorry, I just assumed it was you when you posted the "good for you comment"  My apologies.